# Redirect urls if contains some Non-English characters using htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, non-english

I want to redirect any urls that contains some phrases such as **تصفیه-آب**

For example the below urls must redirect to an exact new url:

```
example.com/sale-دستگاه-تصفیه-آب-قیمت
example.com/products/تصفیه-آب-sale/
```

I am using this code in .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (^|/)sss(/|$) http://example.com [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Now any urls that contains "sss" will redirect to my new url.But if i change the "sss" to my non-English word, will not redirect.

After this step, I want redirect many other urls that contains some characters.I need the new code that work with multiple condition and multiple destination urls.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://serverfault.com/a/130487/175221) may be of help?

Comment: How can i change from ANSI as UTF-8  rather than UTF-8?Notepad has not this item

Comment: I believe that it's [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) that does this, not Notepad.

Comment: I could not find any item named "ANSI as UTF-8" in encoding menu of notpadd++ 6.7.9

Comment: Looks like it has changed. Please try using "UTF-8 without BOM".